# Log4j2 RollingFile with daily rotation

Tags: log4j2

Using Log4j2 2.8, is there a way to have my logs rotate daily but so that the current file has a constant name?

Example:

```
my.log <-- current day (2017-02-13)
my-2017-02-12.log <-- last log
my-2017-02-11.log <-- second to last log
```

I tried the following configuration without success:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFileMain" fileName="my.log"
             filePattern="my-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%level{length=1} %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{-3} (%F:%L) %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2"/>
</RollingFile>
```

Additionally, I get the following exception when I launch my application for the first time on a given day:

```
2017-02-14 09:28:38,334 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender RollingFileMain java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.AbstractRolloverStrategy.getEligibleFiles(AbstractRolloverStrategy.java:107)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.AbstractRolloverStrategy.getEligibleFiles(AbstractRolloverStrategy.java:96)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.AbstractRolloverStrategy.getEligibleFiles(AbstractRolloverStrategy.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending(DefaultRolloverStrategy.java:212)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge(DefaultRolloverStrategy.java:199)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.rollover(DefaultRolloverStrategy.java:326)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.rollover(RollingFileManager.java:310)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.rollover(RollingFileManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.checkRollover(RollingFileManager.java:207)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:267)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:403)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2091)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1988)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1960)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:1297)
    at my.package.MainKt.main(Main.kt:48)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be a combination of @Remko Popma's answer and a bug in Log4j2 **2.8**. After applying the `filePattern="my-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"` and downgrading to version **2.7**, everything works as expected.

I submitted an issue regarding the crash here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1815

Comment: The issue mentions adding '.\' before the path as a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Please change your filepattern to `filePattern="my-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"`:

The %i is only useful when you use the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy. If you only have a TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, Log4j gets confused by the %i...

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I edited my question to include an exception I get when I try this.